# Android BroadcastReceiver does not work phone calls

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I was looking for examples.

My class look like:

```
<pre><code>

package com.example.pjimnez.samsung_auto_reply;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        //IntentFilter screenStateFilter;
        Button btnStart;
        TextView txtHome;


        //PhoneState oPhoneState;

        IntentFilter filter1;



        private final BroadcastReceiver myPhoneState = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

                if (state == null) {

                    //Outgoing call
                    String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

                    Toast.makeText(context, number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {

                    //Log.e("tag", "EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK");

                    Toast.makeText(context, "EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {

                    //Log.e("tag", "EXTRA_STATE_IDLE");
                    Toast.makeText(context, "EXTRA_STATE_IDLE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {

                    //Incoming call
                    String number = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                    //Log.e("tag", "Incoming number : " + number);
                    Toast.makeText(context, number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else
                    Toast.makeText(context, "none", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


        };







        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            filter1 = new IntentFilter(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED);
            registerReceiver(this.myPhoneState, filter1);


            btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);// Instancia del objeto boton intro

            //No funciona en modo escucha
            btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    txtHome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtHome);
                    txtHome.setText("Dio click en el boton!" );//cambio el contenido del TextView

                    //Envia el mensahe SMS
                    /*
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage("5524234613", null, "Mensaje de prueba", null, null);
                    */
                }
            });


        }




    }

    enter code here

</code></pre>
```

My manifest has permissions to:

android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE

android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS

android.permission.SEND_SMS

The problem is that my app never show the message on phone change state

i do not know whats is wrong with the BroadcastReceiver

Could you helpme

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

1-   add a class PhoneStateBroadcastReceiver which extends BroadcastReceiver and overwrite onReceive()

2- at runtime, request PHONE_STATE permission upfront

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(myMainActivity,
        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
        READ_PHONE_STATE_CODE);
```

and give it via the system dialog

3- make a phone call

You'll see the intent caught in onReceive():

intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.READ_PHONE_STATE flg=0x10 cmp=com.myApp.network.PhoneStateBroadcastReceiver (has extras) }
Action: android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE

Hope it helps

Comment: Care to explain what it does and how/why it solves the problem at hand?